# How I could define a inner product in the characters in $SL(2, \mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups

I have homework in a course on Lie groups, in which I must show that $(\pi_m,\mathbb C_m[x,y])$ are the only irreducible representations of finite dimension in SL(2,ℝ). Here $ C_m[x,y])$ is the vector space of homogeneous polynomials, and $\pi_m(g)$ acts via $\pi_m(g)(f(x,y))=f((x,y)\cdot g)$. It was not too complicated to calculate the characters, taking the basis $\{p_k:0\leq k \leq n\}$ with $p_k = x^ky^{n−k}$, since $\pi_m(exp(H))p_k=exp(d\pi_m(H))p_k=exp(2k−n)p_k$, but the question is how one could define an inner product for these matrices. But, I don't have the volume form of SL(2,ℝ) to define the integral $\langle f,g \rangle=\int_Gf(z)⋅\overline{g(z)}dz$

Comment: $(x,y) \dot \ g$ means the multiplication of the vector $(x,y)$ by a matrix of $SL_2(R)$ ? and [wikipedia says that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SL2(R)#Finite-dimensional_representations) it is a consequence of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SU(2) )

Comment: Yes, $g\in SL(2,\mathbb R)$, and $\cdot$ means usual multiplication

Comment: I am not sure whether you are on the right track looking for an inner product on characters. You can take the infinitesimal representation of the Lie algebra and extend it to the complexification $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$. In the complex case it is easy to show that a representation is uniquely determined by its dimension up to isomorphism. (One constructs a basis out of a highest weight vector.) To proceed via characters, it would probably be necessary to use the unitary trick to relate to representations of $SU(2)$.